# Why we use async on main thread

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

> Updating UI on a thread other than the main thread is a common mistake that can result in missed UI updates, visual defects, data corruptions, and crashes.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker

Example:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
   if let data = data {
      DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct
         self.label.text = "\(data.count) bytes downloaded"
      }
   }
}
task.resume()
```

My question starts here -
I am confused with above statement when we say `.async` means not simultaneously (Or not parallel) with `.main`. Can someone explain my problem?

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async` means you queue up a task in the main queue, without waiting the task to be executed. The main queue tasks will be run on the main thread one by one automatically, scheduled by the OS.

Comment: Think of each `DispatchQueue` as a worker. Calling `.async` adds a task under the worker's TODO list and do not wait for the worker to finish the task. `DispathQueue.main` is the specific worker that work on the main thread.

Comment: @RickyMo can we write it as `DispatchQueue.main.sync` ?

Comment: `.sync` will block the thread until the task block has finished executing. You can call `.sync` on any thread other than the main thread since main thread must not be blocked. That doesn't means you cannot call `DispatchQueue.main.sync`. You can call `DispatchQueue.main.sync` just like any custom `dispathQueue.sync` on non- main thread. e.g. `DispatchQueue(label: "bgqueue", qos: .background).async{ DispatchQueue.main.sync{} }` is OK. But `DispatchQueue.main.asycn{ DispatchQueue.main.sync{} }` is NOT.

Comment: `.sync` is usually not quite useful. If you want something to happen after a main queue task, you just queue that "something" into the main queue too. It is not worth to block a thread if not necessary.

Comment: @RickyMo as you added `DispatchQueue(label: "bgqueue", qos: .background).async{ DispatchQueue.main.sync{} }` in there i think `DispatchQueue.main.sync{}` (insider block) comes out of thread(bgqueue)? Means there is only two thread Main & bgqueue

Comment: Yes. In that case, A task is issued from `bgqueue` to `main` then `bgqueue` is blocked to wait for the task on `main` to be finished.

Comment: Though it is very rare to use `.sync`, there are two rules to remember when using `.sync`, regardless of which queue is receiving the `.sync` call : 1. never call `.sync` from a queue to itself, which causes deadlock. 2. never call `.sync` from main queue, which blocks the UI thread.

Comment: @RickyMo thanks . I am clear now. Please add as answer which help us all & can upvote. 
:)

Comment: by doing DispatchQueue.main.async {} you are accessing the main thread from some other thread asynchronously. That means the current thread will continue without waiting for the main thread to finish the provided closure.

Answer (score 6):

`DispatchQueue.main.async` means you queue up a task in the main queue, without waiting the task to be executed. The main queue tasks will be run on the main thread one by one automatically, scheduled by the OS.

Think of each `DispatchQueue` as a worker. Calling `.async` adds a task under the worker's TODO list and do not wait for the worker to finish the task. `DispathQueue.main` is the specific worker that work on the main thread.

Oh the other hand, `.sync` will block the thread until the task block has finished executing. You can call `.sync` on any thread other than the main thread since main thread must not be blocked.

That doesn't means you cannot call `DispatchQueue.main.sync`. You can call DispatchQueue.main.sync just like any custom dispathQueue.sync on non- main thread.

e.g.

```
DispatchQueue(label: "bgqueue", qos: .background).async
{ 
    DispatchQueue.main.sync{} 
}
```

is OK.

But

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{ 
    DispatchQueue.main.sync{} 
}
```

is NOT.

`.sync` is usually not quite useful. If you want something to happen after a main queue task, you just queue that "something" into the main queue too. It is not worth to block a thread if not necessary.

That being said, here are two rules to remember when using `.sync`, regardless of which queue is receiving the `.sync` call :

1. never call `.sync` from a queue to itself, which causes deadlock.
2. never call `.sync` from main queue, which blocks the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused how `DispatchQueue` works.

`DispatchQueue` simply manages thread pool, and when we give it a block of code to execute it simply picks an idle thread and run that piece of code on it.

So basically one thread can be used by many queues. A queue is simply a task list which manages all the tasks which will execute in future.

So basically here when you are doing `DispatchQueue.main.async` then you are simply instructing `main queue` to execute your code without waiting for pending tasks execution.