# Should I set async to UIView animate or not?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to update frame with animation and I'm not sure should it be wrapped in DispatchQueue.main.async or not

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: Constant.selectionIndicatorAnimationTime) {
                self.selector.frame = frame
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why we use async on main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586989/why-we-use-async-on-main-thread)

Comment: Only if you are calling `UIView.animate` from a queue other than main.